# Is there a way to dynamically use a Custom Permission selected through Apex on a Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, winter15

I know its a little to early too ask questions about features being given in Winter 15, however any help is greatly appreciated :)

[Custom permissions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/securityImplGuide/Content/custom_perms_overview.htm) is a new feature provided in Winter 15.

My requirement is that, client will store custom permission names in a custom setting(hierarchy). There will be a Visualforce page with some buttons. The visibility to those buttons are configured based on the custom permissions.
Therefore I want to select the Custom permission name from the custom setting via apex code and send it to Visualforce page.

I have successfully tried it out based on http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_permission.htm

***Is there any way to do similar stuff dynamically?***